# Remove duplicate items from the array retracted from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, dictionary, duplicates

I am building a Blog app and I am trying to get results but it is showing duplicate results, I am trying to remove the duplicate results from the array.

But the problem is there are `two key and values` in each dict inside array, One is unique and other can be same so I am trying to distinct based on same array, It worked But the other `key and value` pair (which is unique) is not attaching with the other pair.

response which is returning from db

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "user_1"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "user_3"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "user_3"
    }
]
```

App.js

```
function App() {
   const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

   axios.get("retract_blogs/").then((res) => {
   
      // Here I also want to attach "id"
      setBlogs({[...new Set(res.data.data.map(x => x.name))]})

   }

   return(
     <div>
       {
         blogs.map((user) =>
          <div>
             {user.name}

             // Here I wamt to show ID
             // {user.id}

          </div>
       }
     </div>
   )
}
```

I want to add `id` with `x.username`, I also tried using

```
setBlogs({data:[...new Set(res.data.data.map(x => x.name, x.id))]})
```

But it showed

> x is not defined

But I am trying to add both `name` and `id`, and remove duplicates based on name not id.

I have tried many times but it is still not working.

Comment: Which `id` do you want to keep for duplicates? To keep the last occurence you can simply make a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the array keyed by `name` and then convert back to an array. `const result = [...new Map(res.data.data.map((user) => [user.name, user])).values()];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the `id` of the last occurence you can create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the array keyed by `name` and then convert back to an array using the iterator returned by [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values). This works by overwriting earlier entries in the Map with the same name.

```js
const users = [{ "id": 2, "name": "user_1" }, { "id": 3, "name": "user_3" }, { "id": 4, "name": "user_3" }];

const result = [...new Map(users.map((user) => [user.name, user])).values()];

console.log(result);
// [ { id: 2, name: 'user_1' }, { id: 4, name: 'user_3' } ]
```

If you instead want to keep the `id` of the first occurence of a name you can use a slightly modified 'group by' grouping into an object by `name` (here in a [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) call, but it could easily be done in a standard loop as well) before taking the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). This works by only setting the `accumulator[name]` property if it doesn't already exist, here using [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

```js
const users = [{ "id": 2, "name": "user_1" }, { "id": 3, "name": "user_3" }, { "id": 4, "name": "user_3" }];

const result = Object.values(users.reduce((a, c) => (a[c.name] ??= c, a), {}));

console.log(result);
// [ { id: 2, name: 'user_1' }, { id: 3, name: 'user_3' } ]
```